# ASP.NET impersonation?

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, act

I just installed Act premium for web on my Windows Server 2003.

I'm reading through the instructions it says to create an asp.net impersonation account but it doesn't give any details on how (because apparently it's different for each version of Windows).

Does anyone know how to create something like this so I can get this app up and running?

Sorry, I'm a little vague.  I'm pretty new to the whole webapp hosting in-house thing so if I left anything out please tell me in the comments and I'll Edit the OP.

UPDATE:
This is the error i get from the page

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Error reading configuration information from the registry.

Source Error:

Line 61:        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
Line 62: 
Line 63:     <identity impersonate="true" userName="registry:HKLM\Software\AspNetProcess\ASPNET_SETREG,userName" password="registry:HKLM\Software\AspNetProcess\ASPNET_SETREG,password"/>
Line 64:        <pages enableViewState="true" enableSessionState="true" theme="ACT" autoEventWireup="false" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false">
Line 65:            <controls>


Source File: C:\Program Files\ACT\ACT for Web\APFW\web.config    Line: 63
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into this issue myself, but according to MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(VS.80).aspx)) they don't mention the ability to use registry keys for web.config *for .NET v2.0*. However, for .NET v1.1 they mention registry keys ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(VS.71).aspx)).

Again, since I don't have direct experience with this particular error, I'd think that ACL/permissions may be an issue for IIS being unable to read from the registry. According to yet another [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx) they mention:

> Any Windows resources, such as files
>   and registry keys, must have an access
>   control list (ACL) that grants access
>   to the process identity.

In the documentation about ASP.NET v1.1 impersonation they specifically mention:

> You should configure access to the key
>   storing the encrypted credentials so
>   that access is provided only to
>   Administrators and SYSTEM. Because the
>   key will be read by the ASP.NET
>   process running as SYSTEM, you should
>   set the following permissions:
>   - Administrators:F
>   - SYSTEM:F
>   - CREATOR OWNER:F
>   - ProcessAccount:R

Hope this helps lead to an fix/answer.

Comment: thanks for the +1. Please keep the thread updated with any new info for the community. I'm interested to know the root issue and the fix as I work extensively with ASP.NET webapps.